# Website availability in percentage in grafana (SLA)

Tags: grafana, zabbix

I have 2 web application availability metrics in zabbix:

1. 200 or not
2. 1 - down, 0 - up

Is it possible to display website availability data as a percentage in grafana? Desirable with reference to datetime

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup, and was just able to accomplish this. First thing to note is that my values are inverse of yours ( 1 = Up, 0 = Down ) so you will need to account for that.

Entirely in Grafana:

- Add a function to the query to scale(100)
- Value Options > Calculation > Mean
- Standard Options > Unit > Percent (0-100)

I played around a bit and found that by not scaling it and then setting the unit to Percent (0.0-1.0) the resulting calculation is not accurate.